# How to add horizontal Scrollbar on TileControl?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm trying to add a horizontal scrollbar on my `(DevExpress) TileControl` in Visual Studio 2010, but I always fail. I know that when you create a `TileControl` you can automatically scroll with the mouse wheel, but how do I add a Horizontal Scroll bar, too?

Comment: '
TileControl1.AllowDrag("HScrollBar1.Value")
 TileControl1.Text = HScrollBar1
 HScrollBar1 =  TileControl1.Text = HScrollBar1
'

I've tried Simple codes like I wrote. I tried to put them in all subs, classes. Didn't worked. I'm new on TileControl so I don't know much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the [TileControl.ScrollMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsTileControl_ScrollModetopic) property:

```
tileControl1.ScrollMode = TileControlScrollMode.ScrollBar;
```